# React.js with ESlint settings

Tags: reactjs, eslint

When I use ESLint check my code, I got this error---'React' is defined but never used no-unused-vars

```
import React from 'react';
const app=({})=>{
    return <div>123</div>;
};
export default app;
```

How could I modify my .eslintrc.json file to fix this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`eslint-plugin-react`](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react) eslint plugin which introduces React specific linting rules for eslint.

Simply you can install it with npm and configure it in your eslint config file.

`npm install eslint-plugin-react --save-dev`

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "react"
  ]
}
```

and then you need enable [`react/jsx-uses-react`](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-uses-react.md) rule in eslint config file.

```
"rules": {
   // other rules,
   "react/jsx-uses-react": 2
}
```

Or you can you enable all recommended eslint-plugin-react configs with `extends` property.

```
{
  "extends": [... /*other presets*/, "plugin:react/recommended"]
}
```

However, this will enable some [additional rules](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react#recommended) also which enforces React good practices.

Comment: Also along with `eslint` I highly recommend using [prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier). Its an awesome tool to format your code after running `eslint`.